# Как совмещать rest API и возможности шаблонизаторов?

Tags: java, spring

Говорят, сейчас рулит rest, но зачем в таком случае существуют шаблонизаторы? Или это прошлый век? Либо они друг другу не мешают и используются одновременно, но если так, то объясните, пожалуйста, кто за что отвечает. Если вопрос глупый извиняюсь - я чайник.

Comment: В качестве учебного пособия. В реальных проектах не видел чтобы они применялись.

Comment: Rest для манипуляции данными, а шпаблонизаторы для 
удобной  отрисовки этих данных

Comment: посмею усомниться в комментарии `AlekseiGaile`. Шаблонизаторы использовались, используются и как мне кажется будут использоваться. Существует огромное множество подходов и у всех есть свои плюсы и минусы. Также как и вполне себе можно совмещать отображение с шаблонизатором и работу с REST. Хотя часто используют либо одно либо другое.

Answer (score 0):

На самом деле вопрос закономерный для новичка. Для того, чтобы ответить на него, давайте разберемся зачем нужно одно и другое.

`Rest`. Когда мы пишем некий `rest` сервис, то мы подразумеваем некий [`API`](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/API) нашего приложения. Причем `API` этот может быть использован в различных целях. Его могут использовать `front`, `android` или другие `back` приложения. Таким образом, мы отделяем логику отображения от самой логики сервиса. Как все это будем выглядеть для пользователя определяет клиент нашего сервиса. [`SPA`](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9E%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5) является примером такой архитектуры.

Шаблонизаторы. Когда мы используем шаблонизаторы вроде `thymeleaf` или `freemarker`, мы упрощаем ситуацию и отдаем отображение пользователю напрямую. Как минус, наш сервис уже не на столько универсален и должен сам решать как отображать пользователю данные.

Часто бывают сервисы, которые комбируют подходы.